# Logistic regression, what if we need to look at the 0 in the target variable?

Tags: r, statistics, binary, logistic-regression

A question about the logistic regression,

1. what if we need to look at the target variable that should be 0 ?  so we count 0 as the goal , we need to modify the data.frame and transform all 0 of the target variable to 1.
2. and the same for independent variables ? ( if we need to say that they are important to us if they are 0'es ?

examples:
A)
if the target variable should be 1, and independent variables are 0 ( we look for independent variables that are 0) => here we need to transform the independent variables 0 to 1 and 1 to 0 and left the target variable as it ?

B) if the studied target variable should be  0 and independent variables also 0, so here we need to transform all 0 to 1 both dependent and independent variables ?

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow. If you have general questions about the appropriate use of various statistical models, then you should ask such questions over at [stats.se] instead. You are more likely to get better answers there. I'm not sure you need to recode, just make sure you correctly interpret your results.

Comment: Thank you, Mr. Flick, how to interpret these points if using R ? thank you in advance.

Comment: Interpretation of coefficients isn't at all influenced by your choice of programming language, thus this really is a statistics question and not a programming question. If this really is just a recoding issue, then you could improve your question by including a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.